# Proper way to connect to MySQL DB from Java

Tags: java, mysql, object, static, database-connection

Which is the best way to handle a MySql connection with Java, via static context or Object one?

Static context:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbd.Driver");

        Connection con = DBHandler.getConnection();

        //Using connection
    }
}


public class DBHandler {
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        final String URL = "";
        final String USER = "";
        final String PASS = "";

        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }
}
```

Or creating an object:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbd.Driver");

        Connection con = new DBHandler().getConnection();

        //Using connection
    }
}


public class DBHandler {
    private final Connection con;

    public DBHandler() {
        final String URL = "";
        final String USER = "";
        final String PASS = "";

        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }
}
```

I think creating an object in every class you need to use the connection is weird but maybe it's the best way to solve that.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's a matter of general opinion. Opening a `Connection` is expensive, so you tend to want to reduce the number of times you open one, but you also need to consider what happens in the connection breaks for some reason (was accidently closed, time out, some other error). If you're using a single thread for all your queries, then using a single connection isn't a bad idea, but if you're using multiple threads, you might find it better to use multiple connections, at which point some kind of connection pool might be in order